# Auto generate passwords from CSV imported users

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I need to upload users from a csv file then generate a hashed password for each user . I'm using CodeIgniter and PHPass for hashing passwords .. my question is which is the better way to generate those passwords .. **Before importing those files to my database** or **After I have imported the file to my database**  . I'm still a noob .. an example or a simple structure would help alot . Thank you

I have this class as a library

```
class users {

public function upload_csv_users () {

// code for uploading users goes here 

}

public function generate_passwords() {

// code for generating password for each user goes here 

}
```

then from my controller i want to upload users then generate each user his/her unique password

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just do it the same time you add them from CSV. Was that the whole question?

Comment: will it be secure enough as from what im thinking i will have to write those passwords to the csv file then upload it .. i dont know the way i should retrieve the uploaded users from database that matches with the list from the csv file

Comment: Oh... ok then I'm not sure what you're doing here.

Comment: Ok .. thanx anyway for your suggestion ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to have a temp_users table and import your password-less users to this table.  Do you have emails for these users?  If so, then instead of setting a password, you could set a random identifier in the table associated with that temporary user and send them a link in the email (that contains a url paramenter ?identifier=sfsdfsdfsdf)  Then when they click on the link in their email, they are sent to a "confirm account" method (which checks the random url parameter against the one stored with their temp_user), asked to set a password, and are then (on success) deleted from the temp_users table and added to the "active" users table.  This would solve most of your security questions and at the same time, allow them to set their own passwords.

Comment: from my application i provide them with two options . either to generate random passwords for each user or just let them choose their own passwords on a confirmation email sent to them .. so does that mean generating passwords wont be secure enough same as letting users choose their own passwords .. ?

Comment: Well, how are they going to know what the password is that you generate for them? Are you sending it to them in an email in plain text (because that isn't secure), or are you displaying it to them on the screen (potentially also not secure)?

Comment: Either way, if you are a 'noob' I highly recommend you go through this tutorial over on YouTube...it's a decent tutorial and by chance just happens to show what I was talking about regarding temp_users, etc...  It may be helpful http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL161C7E0E6A01B1E0

Comment: Yeah...that is TERRIBLE practice.  Do not EVER send a password to a user in plain text. It's not even advisable to display a password on a screen.  That is why password inputs have dots and not plain text.